# update a custom property for a member as admin in c#

Tags: ektron

I have added a custom property for members and would like to create a routine that loops through all the members and initializes the custom property.

Im using Ektron Version 8.5 sp1

Here are the two methods that I have tried:
Method 1 - This method does not return the userData object

```
var userManager = new Ektron.Cms.Framework.User.UserManager(Ektron.Cms.Framework.ApiAccessMode.Admin);
var userData = userManager.GetItem(userManager.UserId, true);
userData.CustomProperties["Year 7 Year"].Value = newYear7Year;
userManager.Update(userData);
```

Method 2 - Im concerned this won't work because I don't specify the ApiAccessMode to be Admin

```
var commonApi = new Ektron.Cms.CommonApi();
var userApi = new Ektron.Cms.API.User.User();
var userData = userApi.GetUser(commonApi.UserId, false, false);
userData.CustomProperties["Year 7 Year"].Value = newYear7Year;
userApi.UpdateUser(userData);
```

How should I update the Member?

Answer (score 0):

I have custom properties that I update.  I update them when the user creates an account but I don't think this is any different.
I don't use the CommonApi.
Here is the basics of what I do:

```
Ektron.Cms.API.User.User userApi = new Ektron.Cms.API.User.User();
Ektron.Cms.UserData userData = userApi.GetUser(PUT_USER_ID_HERE);
userData.CustomProperties[keyName].Value = value;
userApi.UpdateUser(userData);
```

The value of PUT_USER_ID_HERE determines which user will be updated.
I didn't need to do anything special with an Admin User or anything like that so hopefully it won't be a problem for you either.